# string in c#. replace certain number in a loop

Tags: c#, string

I have string. "12341234115151_log_1.txt"  (this string length is not fixed. but "*log*" pattern always same)
I have a for loop. 
each iteration, I want to set the number after "log" of i.

like "12341234115151_log_2.txt"
"12341234115151_log_3.txt"
....

to
"12341234115151_log_123.txt"

in c#, what is a good way to do so?
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for regular expression: \d+_log_(\d+).txt

Comment: So you want to make the log files look like this: `12341234115151_log_1.txt,12341234115151_log_12.txt, 12341234115151_log_123.txt, 12341234115151_log_1234.txt`

etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex is ideal for this. You can use the `Regex.Replace` method and use a `MatchEvaluator` delegate to perform the numerical increment.

```
string input = "12341234115151_log_1.txt";
string pattern = @"(\d+)(?=\.)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
    m => (int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString());
```

The pattern breakdown is as follows:

- `(\d+)`: this matches and captures any digit, at least once
- `(?=\.)`: this is a look-ahead which ensures that a period (or dot) follows the number. A dot must be escaped to be a literal dot instead of a regex metacharacter. We know that the value you want to increment is right before the ".txt" so it should always have a dot after it. You could also use `(?=\.txt)` to make it clearer and be explicit, but you may have to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` if your filename extension can have different cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex. like this

```
    var r = new Regex("^(.*_log_)(\\d).txt$")
    for ... {

        var newname = r.Replace(filename, "${1}"+i+".txt");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to get the counter, then just append them together.

If I've read your question right...

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
for (int i =0; i<some condition; i++)
{
  string name = "12341234115151_log_"+ i.ToString() + ".txt";
}
```